# Как присвоить вывод функции в строку

Tags: linux, c, строки, функции

Нужно внести в строку вывод функции `system("ls")`. Если делать через 
`sprintf(str, "%s", system("ls"))`, то прога вылетает. Как мне сделать вывод из функции в строку?

Comment: Может, лучше разобраться, почему прога вылетает? Какая ошибка-то, что в логах?

Comment: Segmetation fault (core dumped)

Comment: тут есть ответ на этот вопрос
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix

Comment: тут есть ответ, как получить результат из потока вывода.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix

Answer (score 3):

возврат функции system код завершения программы вызываемой и это целое число. В вашем случае код завершения будет 0. Вывод строки с адресом 0 (NULL) естественно вызовет ошибку. Для получения результата следует использовать  int pipe(int pipefd[2]) и считывать из стандартного ввода этой 'трубы' (pipefd[0])

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/wait.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int pipefd[2];
       pid_t cpid;
       char buf;

       if (argc != 2) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
           perror("pipe");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       cpid = fork();
       if (cpid == -1) {
           perror("fork");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */

           while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
               write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);

           write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
           close(pipefd[0]);
           _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

       } else {            /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
           close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
           write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
           wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child */
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Я не понял. Можно, пожалуйста, небольшой пример

Comment: сунул выше пример кода

Comment: *fork()* без *exec()* -- плохая затея.

Comment: это выдержка из man. Еще возражения есть?

Answer (score 1):

Всё проще. Надо сделать так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE * ff;
    char buf[1024];

    ff = popen("ls", "r");
    if (ff == NULL) {
        perror("popen");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, 1024, ff) ) {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
}
```

popen передаёт вывод команды, которую она выполняет через канал, который она открывает.

Comment: Если так сделать, то выводит дофига левых символов между названиями файлов((

Comment: @FiLCh **выводит дофига левых символов** Не понял - что значит "левые" символы? Запустил пример с сохранением вывода в лог-файл и внимательно его посмотрел. Между названиями файлов только символы перевода строки. Даже в 16-ричном виде проверял - нет ничего лишнего. Вы где и как запускаете данный пример?